# include_path в php.ini не работает

Tags: php, сервер, php.ini, php-nginx

Система NGINX без APACHE
в фале php.ini прописал `include_path = ".:/var/www/main_lib"`

[image: Информация из phpinfo]

запустил `phpinfo();`
надписи выводит какие нужно НО когда запускаю файл в котором должен сработать  include_path по умолчанию - пишет следующее

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'GoodWheels/CUrlClass.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

Я в ступоре: где сидит эта настройка по умолчанию `include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear'` - эта гадость появилась после установки пакета pear

Вопрос где еще нужно прописать что бы заработала нужная мне библиотека. Про `set_include_path`
я знаю и это не вариант прописывать его в n файлах

Comment: include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear' - в php.ini такой надписи нет

Comment: делайте инклуд по абсолютным путям, инициализировав константу или переменную с ним

Comment: @Naumov это не пойдет у меня масса инклудов  завязанных на пространстве имен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается в коде были применены вызовы консольных команд, а php.ini для консоли другой /etc/php5/cli - чтобы найти расположение этого файла пришлось через консоль запустить php файл с этим кодом

```
ob_start();
phpinfo(); 
$a=ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('php.info.html',$a);
echo 'ok';
```

причем чтобы не нарушать права - выполнил из под рута, предварительно перешел в эту папку командой cd

потом загуглил как перезапускать php на сервере, оказалось что изменения в фале /etc/php5/cli/php.ini не требует перезапуска и все заработало - вот такие танцы с бубнами

Comment: ну это проще делаеться `php --ini`